# cheese show me blank screen but bright webcam is on

Tags: drivers, usb, video, brightness, webcam

I recently installed usbip-win on local PC and usbip on vps Ubuntu 22.04. It's all OK.

Through usbip from Ubuntu I can attach to my peripheral USB windows. When I execute cheese command from terminal I get this errors:

```
(cheese:222425): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 10:52:51.868: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed

(cheese:222425): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 10:52:52.101: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed
```

If I check with dmesg there are:

```
bigissue@vmi995554:~$ sudo dmesg|grep video
[50716.461304] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[50716.478551] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[52980.855183] uvcvideo 2-1:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-1).
[53067.643330] uvcvideo 2-1:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-1).
[53502.168691] uvcvideo 2-1:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-1).
[53502.809206] uvcvideo 2-1:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-1).
[53669.071532] uvcvideo 2-1:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-1).
[53841.982850] uvcvideo 2-1:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-1).
[53841.985208] uvcvideo 2-1:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-1).
[55244.087507] uvcvideo 2-1:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-1).
```

I confirm that usbip client is connected to server

```
bigissue@vmi995554:~$ sudo usbip port
Imported USB devices
====================
Port 00: <Port in Use> at High Speed(480Mbps)
       Realtek Semiconductor Corp. : unknown product (0bda:57c3)
       2-1 -> usbip://95.244.92.114:3240/1-2
           -> remote bus/dev 001/002
```

Comment: Thank you David for edited it. Can you help me?

Comment: I have tried usb network gate software, it's has same problem, black screen.